# nginx default configuration files

Tags: nginx

What does it mean when I see both "nginx.conf" and "nginx.conf.default" configuration files?  I also see "fastcgi.conf" and "fastcgi.conf.default" and "fastcgi.params" and "fastcgi.params.default" etc, in the same folder.

Does ".conf.default" get applied and then the ".conf" gets applied on top of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx will strictly load the configuration from the .conf files unless you haven't specified otherwise (like using an include rule and include a file with other extension that .conf).

.conf.default files are not applied on top of the .conf files. In fact they are not applied at all.

As far as I know this behaviour appears on debian when you do update nginx (but I might be wrong).

Comment: Thanks, @Bogdan Stoica.  I'm assuming any file will be ignored unless explicitly include'ed right?

Comment: Thx.  So will .conf files be included even if I don't include them from nginx.conf?

Comment: the .conf files from /etc/nginx are included by default. Also the files from conf.d files. Any other files should be manually specified or included. The .conf.default files are not loaded by default.